# Facing issue to integrate airflow 2.2.2 with SQL Server as meta store

Tags: sql-server, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm facing an issue when trying to integrate airflow 2.2.2 with SQL Server as meta store:

Microsoft SQL Server 2019

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ab_permission' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL: INSERT INTO ab_permission (id, name) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR ab_permission_id_seq, ?)]
> [parameters: ('can_read',)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

Answer (score 0):

Airflow does not support MSSQL in 2.2 line. It's coming in 2.3 as experimental support.

https://github.com/apache/airflow#requirements

|  | Main version (dev) | Stable version (2.2.2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Python | 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 | 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 |
| Kubernetes | 1.18, 1.19, 1.20 | 1.18, 1.19, 1.20 |
| PostgreSQL | 9.6, 10, 11, 12, 13 | 9.6, 10, 11, 12, 13 |
| MySQL | 5.7, 8 | 5.7, 8 |
| SQLite | 3.15.0+ | 3.15.0+ |
| MSSQL(Experimental) | 2017, 2019 |  |